# Get the Folder GUID using Power Shell

Tags: development, powershell, pnp-powershell

I am trying to get the folder GUID using its URL, i tried this power shell:-

```
#Variables
$SiteURL = "https://*****.sharepoint.com"
$ServerRelativeUrl= "/Shared Documents/FolderA"
 
Try {

 
    #Setup the context
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://******.sharepoint.com -UseWebLogin
    $Ctx =  Get-PnPContext

    #Get the web from URL
    $Web = $Ctx.web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)
    $Ctx.executeQuery()
 
    #Get the Folder object by Server Relative URL
    $Folder = $Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($ServerRelativeUrl)
    $Ctx.Load($Folder)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
     
    #Get Some Folder Properties
    Write-host -f Green "Folder GUID:"$Folder.GUID
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error Getting Folder!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

but i did not get any result. any advice?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change one line in your code like below. And it will work. (i.e., You need to explicitly mention `ListItemAllFields` while loading folder)

```
$Ctx.Load($Folder.ListItemAllFields)   ## This line is changed from your code (i.e., loading `ListItemAllFields`)
$folderGuid = $Folder.ListItemAllFields["GUID"]
```

There is another way to get the folder. Refer below code, it should work for you.

```
$Folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $ServerRelativeUrl -Includes ListItemAllFields
$folderGuid = $Folder.ListItemAllFields["GUID"]
```

Comment: Thanks worked for me